# What's the most efficient way to determine the latest revision of a record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm querying against a table which has multiple revisions of each record, but does not store the version number of each record. I have to derive it from a "touched on" date.

I want to retrieve just the latest revision.

I'm waffling between two approaches: `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but I'm not sure which one would perform better. Perhaps it depends on the context, but I'm not sure which considerations to make. I don't know the indexing on these tables.

Are there any significant differences in performance between these two approaches?

`ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  h.header_id,
            h.touched_on,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.header_id ORDER BY h.touched_on DESC) AS revision
    FROM header h
    JOIN event e ON h.serial_no = e.serial_no
    WHERE h.touched_on BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
) noms
WHERE noms.revision = 1
```

`LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  h.header_id,
        h.touched_on,
FROM header h
LEFT OUTER JOIN header h2 ON h2.header_id = h.header_id AND h2.touched_on > h.touched_on
JOIN event e ON h.serial_no = e.serial_no
WHERE h.touched_on BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
AND h2.header_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I mean, you have the data and can test both queries. Anyway, they are not equivalent, and the second one won't return the data that you seem to want

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan for both options?  Does one take noticeably longer than the other?

Comment: First, they are different queries. The second may return multiple raws for a header_id.

Comment: first one will return correct answer.why left join in second one

Comment: @Mani - it's what I used to refer to as an "anti-join". You use a `LEFT JOIN` to find another row that disqualifies the current row (here, by having a later `touched_on` value) and then a `WHERE` clause condition (`h2.header_id IS NULL`) to eliminate rows where the join succeeded. A common way of finding "the latest" the pre-dates `ROW_NUMBER()`, although as already mentioned, it's closer to `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` because of the way it will treat ties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the current (latest) version for *one* particular key then is easy:

```
SELECT TOP(1) ... 
  FROM <table>
  WHERE key = @key
  ORDER BY touched_on DESC;
```

To make this efficient your table should be clustered by `(key, touched_on)`.

However, to retrieve the current (latest) version for a *set* of rows (or all), then the task is difficult, to say the least. A **much** better design is to split the table into two, one holding *current* rows and one holding all history. This is exactly what [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx) in SQL Server 2016 do, this is [what PostgreSQL does](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/6/64/Fosdem20150130PostgresqlTemporal.pdf), this is what DB2 does. Basically no implementation offers time travel by storing all versions of the row in the same table, because **it makes querying current data incredibly expensive**.

You see, your design is *known* to be problematic and inefficient. Is much better to address the problem at the root cause and split the data into `<table_current>` and `<table_history>`.

Comment: Makes sense and I agree, but unfortunately it's not my database to change, I'm just querying it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what will show you your LEFT JOIN query, consider replace it with CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
            h2.header_id,
            h2.touched_on
FROM header h
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM header 
    WHERE header_id = h.header_id 
        and touched_on BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    ORDER BY touched_on DESC) as h2
JOIN [event] e ON h2.serial_no = e.serial_no
WHERE h.touched_on BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to use a [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx): -

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
WITH HeaderEvent
     AS (SELECT h.header_id,
                h.touched_on,
                RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.header_id ORDER BY h.touched_on DESC)
         FROM header h
              JOIN event e ON h.serial_no = e.serial_no
         WHERE h.touched_on BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
     SELECT header_id,
            touched_on
     FROM HeaderEvent
     WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

To compare performance include the following prior to running each query to compare metrics: -

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

You can also investigate the [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn935015.aspx) feature (SQL Server 2016 only) to efficiently store version history of data as an alternative.

Comment: This is the same as the first query op posted